# How to connect to my http://localhost web server from Android Emulator in wampserver?

Tags: android, android-studio, localhost

Yes this question has been asked already, and i have used all the solutions from the previous questions however i have not found a solution.So please do not mark as duplicate.

What can I do in android studio so that my Android emulator can connect to my localhost web server page at http://localhost?

I have tried all of the solutions listed below and i cant seem to get it to work.

What i have tried is listed below:

http://10.0.2.2/login.php

http://10.0.2.2:8080/login.php

http://10.0.3.2/login.php

Used my IPv4 address

This is how i am trying to connect to local host.

```
 String type = params[0];
        String login_url = "http://10.0.2.2 :80/login.php";
        if(type.equals("login")) {
            try {
                String user_name = params[1];
                String password = params[2];
                URL url = new URL(login_url);
                HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
                httpURLConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
                httpURLConnection.setDoOutput(true);
                httpURLConnection.setDoInput(true);
                OutputStream outputStream = httpURLConnection.getOutputStream();
                BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(outputStream, "UTF-8"));
                String post_data = URLEncoder.encode("user_name","UTF-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(user_name,"UTF-8")+"&"
                        +URLEncoder.encode("password","UTF-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(password,"UTF-8");
                bufferedWriter.write(post_data);
                bufferedWriter.flush();
                bufferedWriter.close();
                outputStream.close();
                InputStream inputStream = httpURLConnection.getInputStream();
                BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream,"iso-8859-1"));
                String result="";
                String line="";
                while((line = bufferedReader.readLine())!= null) {
                    result += line;
                }
                bufferedReader.close();
                inputStream.close();
                httpURLConnection.disconnect();
                return result;
            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

Comment: Have you tried `http://localhost/login.php`? And `http://127.0.0.1/login.php`? Maybe your wamp is needing some additional tune, maybe inside httpd.conf... have you check it? Or your .hosts file?

Comment: @statosdotcom tried both of those and they did not work. Where do i need to go to find those two httpd.conf.. file at? would it be located in the wamps file?

Comment: Let's start from the beginning: forget android and android emulator for a while. What happens if you try to access your **login.php** from your default regular system web browser, i.e., via an http connection?

Comment: it works perfectly fine and i even check connection with if statement and it conenction is succesfull. Also looked up my host file and i found this 

# localhost name resolution is handled within DNS itself.
# 127.0.0.1       localhost
# ::1             localhost

Comment: Ok, I was doing some research. This question is very common and you are in the correct way when uses 10.0.2.2 but not 10.0.3.2 - if you are not using genymotion. The only difference I see is it seems you have to explicit use a port number to access localhost from android emu, and you have used 8080, why? It should be only 80, unless you configured your wamp response to 8080 requests...  In other words, have you tried `http://10.0.2.2:80/login.php` ?

Comment: i tried all of those and they dont work. When i went and looked at my files for my wamps it sayst that mysqlPortUsed = "3306" and i tried using that and still no solution. I used 8080 because i have searched online for the past 3 hours and some of these ports worked for others so took a leap of faith and it just didnt work for me.

Comment: Has your Manifest.xml contains the necessary `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />` and `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />` before **application** tag?

Comment: I have all of that. Thank you for the help. :(

Comment: It seems we are missing some point. One thing is clear: if your regular browser opens localhost/login.php this means port 80 it's been used. Forget anyone different from it. I suggest you return to previous pages (here on S.O.) facing the same problem and do a checklist on all the steps. Yet thinking abroad: you probably are trying to access this login page via a webview, yes? There is some error message? What happens, blank page? You didn't say a bit about it. More: are you trying to use some javascript on this webview? Have you enabled javascript and DOM to run inside your webview?

Comment: URL url = new URL(login_url);
HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();

That is how i am trying to connect to it.

Comment: Sincerely, with all my respect, I recommend you try each step at once. Seems you are not too confident on all of this and yet trying to walk faster than your foots can afford. Try firstly open a plain html page, then see the results. If not using a webview, try a simple helloworld through this, something that will require a simple "loadUrl", then investigate the setup of your wamp, the configuration files, read carefully and patiently all those "localhost from emulator" pages here on S.O. etc etc etc. There are many details to see. As the quote says, hurry is the enemy of perfection. Best luck

Comment: `One thing is clear: if your regular browser opens localhost/login.php this means port 80 it's been used`. Ok. But use a regular browser on a different pc first. Not from the pc where the server is running on. Or use a browser from an Android device in the same network first.

Comment: Further i miss the errors/exeptions you get. Look in the logcat and post them here. In your post. Not in a comment.

Comment: @greenapps When i ran the debugger in android stuidio this is what i get.

Connected to the target VM, address: 'localhost:8625', transport: 'socket'

Also i dont get any errors in android studio. When i do anything with the php file and if i manualy inout user and password i connect automatically with the mysql database. Everything with the local host and my database are fine. i just cant figure out the issue with android studios. Also i will put my code in the > now.

Comment: `Also i dont get any errors in android studio. `. Well you will get them in your Android app. In the catch block. And e.printStackTrace() will print them to the logcat. If you cannot connect you will have a SocketTimeOutException. You can place your own log statements in a catch block too. Please tell what you get in the logcat. All you tell makes little sense up to now. And you did not do the tests i asked you to do. Why not?